# Bad charset submitted in jQuery Ajax form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

In my index PHP page I define this charset:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

and in HTML with `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

On this page I submit a form with Ajax (jQuery):

```
$('#action_button').click(function() {
        var azione = $('#form-post').attr('action');
        var datiform = $('#form-post').serialize();
        send = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: azione,
            data: datiform,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                 ...
            },
            success: function(msg){
                ...
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

In the page that receives data I set the header

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

I request post data:

```
$nome = htmlentities(rtrim(ltrim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['nome']))))) ;
```

but the data are not properly registered in the database; the characters òèìùàé are badly interpreted, like ÄÃ and similar. I have tested different ways but without success but if I send the form without Ajax (jQuery) it works fine!

Comment: did you file is in UTF-8 charset? Open your file in some editor and check it charset.

Comment: The [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) documentation states that "Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side." I don't think this is a problem with jQuery

Comment: I think there is a problem with your database collation...

Answer (score 2):

Problem is probably in your database. You can `echo $nome;` to be sure. I would recommend you try connecting to database with this function. Also convert your table charset to  `utf8_unicode_ci`...

```
function connect($server, $database, $username, $password, $charset = "UTF8"){
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $database, $password);
    if(!$link){
        die("Unable to connect to database server.");
    }
    mysql_selectdb($database);
    if(function_exists("mysql_set_charset")){
        mysql_set_charset($charset, $link);
    }else{
        mysql_query("SET NAMES $charset");   
    }
}
```

Set table charset...

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Database...

```
ALTER DATABASE `my_database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```